# superhorizon mode and cmb

Tags: cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

During the period of inflation, perturbations went out of the
Hubble horizon (Hubble radius, R = 1/aH) because the Hubble
radius was decreasing during that time. After inflation, the Hubble
radius increased in size and perturbations re-entered the horizon.
Well, other perturbations are just re-entering right now while
the Hubble radius continues to increase. Perturbations with short 
wavelength entered earlier and therefore became subjected to microphysical 
processes. Perturbations with large wavelength entered late and 
if they entered late enough during the matter-dominated era, they 
effectively become constant.

Superhorizon perturbations are those with wavelength far larger 
than the Hubble radius and a given perturbation maybe  superhorizon
long time ago but became sub horizon at some point in time.
What I'm confused about after reading some papers, is that superhorizon
perturbations with wavelengths far larger than the current Hubble
radius can leave an imprint on the current CMB radiation that we are 
receiving. How is it possible that those CURRENTLY superhorizon-mode
perturbations have an effect on the CMB that we are observing now?

This idea came out of various suggestions on the possibility of 
explaining the dipole asymmetry by using superhorizon modes that are
far larger than the current Hubble radius.

Comment: Just because you don't see a full wavelength doesn't mean you don't see spatial variation in a sinusoid. But I can only guess that's what the authors are referring to - can you provide links to those papers?

Comment: I am currently studying the following papers   arXiv:0808.1570 and related papers about cmb anisotropy.

Comment: I am currently studying the following papers   arXiv:0808.1570, arXiv:0806.0377v3  and related papers about cmb anisotropy. I guess you are correct. These superhorizon perturbations correspond to local gradients. What is confusing is the reconciliation of this idea with the often emphasized concept (or maybe my understanding is wrong) that once a perturbation exits the horizon it becomes causally disconnected and therefore it remains constant.  How can such a causally disconnected perturbation has an effect on the current CMB?